# Correct syntax for dynamic Svelte component and Pug pre-processor

Tags: pug, svelte

Below component

```
<template lang="pug">

  svelte:component.OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel(this="{rootElementTag}")
    span.OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel-TextWithIncreasedLineHeight
      slot

</template>


<script lang="ts" context="module">

  const rootElementTag: string = "div";

</script>
```

causes

```
Uncaught TypeError: switch_value is not a constructor
```

if try to use is as child component.

If to change the root element just to

```
.OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel
```

the error will disappear. But how to make `OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel` dynamic?
I hope it is just my, the novice (for 2021) in Svelte, mistake.

[Source code](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-Frontend/tree/0.3.0/FrameworksIntegrations/Svelte/Package/Tests/OverflowSafeSingleLineLabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much of the pug syntax. But if that `this` relates to `svelte:component`: You can't use `svelte:component` to dynamically create DOM elements, you can only use it to create Svelte components. To achieve what you want, you'll need `svelte:element`, an upcoming feature that is not yet implemented (as of 23.11.2021).

Comment: Thank you fro the answer! Did I understood you correct that currently no such functionality which allows to achieve the desired effect and only left to do is switch/case?

Comment: Yes. The issue that tracks this is https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2324

Comment: Got it! Accepted && upvoted your great answer.